# Query by value of nth element of the array

Tags: mongodb

How do I execute this type of query in mongo?

query:

```
{ 
  luk_array[0].d: -13.62,
}
```

document that should match the query above

```
{
 "_id": ObjectID("59aee5fb0701a85357d0f2c6"),
 "luk_array": [
        {
            "b": 155,
            "c": -0.09,
            "d": -13.62
        },
        {
            "b": 155,
            "c": -0.17,
            "d": -27.05
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `db.collection_name.find({"luk_array.0.d":-13.62});` More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#use-the-array-index-to-query-for-a-field-in-the-embedded-document)

Comment: @Veeram thank you that's great